# Affinity Mask and Affinity I/O Mask

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Using: SQL Server 2008 R2

Under what circumstances would you set the Affinity Mask and Affinity I/O Mask options in sp_configure in SQL Server?

We are currently running on a machine with 16 cores dedicated to SQL Server.  We are also seeing slowness in our I/O operations.  Some writes (insert 1 row) can take up to 500 ms.  We would like to support many writes per second.  The process that inserts data can spawn up to 4 threads for executing the insert operations.

I'm considering dedicating 8 cores to the affinity mask and the other 8 to affinity I/O mask.

Is this recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd consider many other options before I played with these

Some things to check here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2009693/27535

Additionally...

- indexes: are your writes scanning not seeking?
- key: do you have GUIDs as clustered indexes (bad idea!)
- triggers: no emails being sent on INSERT or CURSORs?
- disk layout: separate fast RAIDs for data and logs, *per database*?
- autoshrink/autoclose + associated file growth
- unmaintained statistics and indexes
- ..

Basically, your problem will be poor design poor indexing or poor hardware...